# Bundled several scripts in one bundle.js but I'm having issues with variable access

Tags: javascript, bundle, browserify

I'm working on a project that requires for all the scripts to be incorporated in one bundle.js file. I managed to do this with browserify. The issue here is that while every individual script included in the bundle.js file can execute the contained code perfectly, it can't access global variables from other scripts.
Like in this example. The first script executes perfectly but the second one can't access the sliced variable even though the first script executed correctly and of course, first.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Contents of the first.js script:

```
var a = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
var sliced = a.slice(1, 3);


function logger() {
    console.log(a);      // ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
    console.log(sliced); // ['one', 'two']
    console.log("first.js script executed");
};

logger();
```

Contents of the second.js script:

```
console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: You can try to put your variable in the globals list like `global.sliced = sliced;` which I don't know if is a good idea :)

Comment: I tried that before and it does work. But I agree. It's not the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules do not share global state. You need to import one module into the other just like you would for a server side node script. Then pass in the shared variables. "Bundling" with Browserify is about resolving these imports and saving the results into 1 file since the browser does not understand CommonJS import syntax.

*script.js*

```
let script2 = require('./relative/path/to/script2.js');

let a = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
let sliced = a.slice(1, 3);

function logger() {
    console.log(a);      // ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
    console.log(sliced); // ['one', 'two']
    console.log("first.js script executed");
};

logger();
script2(sliced)
```

*script2.js*

```
function script2PublicFunction (sliced){
    console.log(sliced);
}

module.exports = script2PublicFunction;
```

Comment: Thank you.
This is exactly what I needed.